# Log4j logging not working

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have added `log4j` from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar) in build path. Wrote a simple method to test `log levels` but it doesn't print any thing console.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class LoggerLevelTest {

    private static org.apache.log4j.Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(LoggerLevelTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.setLevel(Level.WARN);

        log.trace("Trace Message!");
        log.debug("Debug Message!");
        log.info("Info Message!");
        log.warn("Warn Message!");
        log.error("Error Message!");
        log.fatal("Fatal Message!");
    }

}
```

**Log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LEVEL">WARN</Property> <!-- default value -->
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="${sys:LEVEL}">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Actual output:

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 2 and column 30
log4j:WARN Document is invalid: no grammar found.
log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (LoggerLevelTest).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Expected Output:

```
Warn Message!
Error Message!
Fatal Message!
```

Above Example link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm

Comment: place log4j.properties file in your classpath

Comment: either of two is needed `.xml` or `.properties` . I have added `.xml`. I have also changed output.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the contents of the `.xml` file you are using.  Given the capital letter `C` in the root element name (`Configuration`) in your output, I'm suspecting this is a Log4j2 configuration file, which won't work with Log4j 1.2.

Comment: excluded slf4j and my problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Your config is in [log4j2 format](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), which is valid, but you need to declare your configuration in `log4j2.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Quite late to the party here. Specifically on the error:

```
log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
```

I found that changing:

```
-Dlog4j2.configuration=...
```

to:

```
-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=...
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml is not valid ... your **Actual output** :

```
log4j:WARN Document root element "Configuration", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
...
log4j:ERROR DOM element is - not a <log4j:configuration> element.
```

I think you should define your xml like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="xyz" ... />

    <root> 
       ...
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```